# Kubernetes: view log of failed container in a deployment

Tags: kubernetes

I created a deployment in which the container always fails, I noticed a new container is automatically created because of the restart policy, but then I am unable to check the log of the failed container. Is there a way to check the log?

Comment: Perhaps better asked on devops SE ?

Comment: https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/pull/2392

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`kubectl logs --previous`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#logs) flag:

> **--previous** *If true, print the logs for the previous instance of the container in a pod if it exists.*

Example:

```
kubectl logs my-pod-crashlooping --container my-container --previous
```